# fundamental groups of complement of lines in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

Consider the 2-dimensional complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$. $H_1$ and $H_2$ are the 1-dimensional subspace determined by $z_1+z_2=0$ and $z_1-z_2=0$ respectively. How to compute the fundamental group and homology groups of $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus(H_1\cup H_2)$ ?
I need help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried expressing the problem in $\mathbb R^4$ instead of $\mathbb C^2$? That might help to understand the regions of the complement. A hyperplane in $\mathbb R^4$ divides the space into two disjoint contractible half spaces.

Comment: Sorry, the last statement doesn't apply here, since $H_1$ and $H_2$ will be 2-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$, not hyperplanes.

Comment: By a change of base, it is sufficient to look at $H_1 = \{z_1 = 0\}$ and $H_2 = \{z_2 =0\}$. That may make it slightly easier to follow.

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel points out in his comment, you may replace $H_1$ and $H_2$ by the coordinate axes $z_1=0, z_2=0$.
Deleting these leaves the space $\mathbb C^*\times \mathbb C^*$ whose fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbb C^*\times \mathbb C^*)$ and  first homology group $H_1(\mathbb C^*\times \mathbb C^*,\mathbb Z)$ are $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.
The second homology group is $H_2(\mathbb C^*\times \mathbb C^*,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$ and the higher homology groups are zero.

Comment: We may repalce $\mathbb{C}^*$ by $\mathbb{R}^2$. So we have $\mathbb{C}^* \$

Comment: We may replace $\mathbb{C}^*$ by $\mathbb{R}^2$. So we have $\mathbb{C}^* \times \mathbb{C}^*\cong (\mathbb{R}^2-{0}) \times (\mathbb{R}^2-{0}) \cong S^1\times S^1 $. We get a torus, right? Thank you very much!

Comment: Dear yang, I think you mean we may replace $\mathbb C^*$ by $\mathbb R^2\setminus 0$, not by $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to find a deformation retraction of $\mathbb{C}^2\backslash
(H_{1}\cup H_{2})$ onto $\mathbb{S}^{1}\times\mathbb{S}^{1}$ (not difficult),
so their groups coincide.

Here again $H_{1}:z_{1}=0$, $H_{2}:z_{2}=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I get it!